# Python Duplicate naming

Tags: python, string, filenames

The goal is to create a naming system for duplicate strings.

If the name is hotdog.jpg and I want to make a duplicate and that the next string is hotdog_1.jpg. And so on. But the problem I'm facing is that if you make a duplicate of hotdog_1.jpg we get hotdog_1_1.jpg. I tried to just check if the string ends with "(underscore) + number". But then the problem is that the string could also have "(underscore) + number + number". like hotdog_13.jpg.

is there any good way to implement this?

```
for current_image_name in self.images_names:
    extension = os.path.splitext(current_image_name)[1]
    current_image_name = os.path.splitext(current_image_name)[0]

    if current_image_name[-2] == '_' and current_image_name[-1].isdigit():
        self.images_names.insert(self.current_index + 1, current_image_name[:-1] + str(int(self.images_names[self.current_index][-1]) + 1) + extension)
        name_change = True

if not name_change:
    self.images_names.insert(self.current_index + 1, self.images_names[self.current_index] + '_1')
```

Comment: A little clarification, what do you expect to happen when the name of the file is hotdog_1.jpg? Are you expecting name collisions (files that already exist)?

Comment: yes, that's right. So all of the file names are stored in a list. So if I want to duplicate the current string in the list, the next item in the list will be hotdog_1.jpg, and if you duplicate that we get hotdog_2.jpg and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a simple method that does some string magic.

**EDITED** after reading the comments on the question. Added a method to handle lists

**code**

```py
def inc_filename(filename: str) -> str:
    if "." in filename:
        # set extension
        extension = f""".{filename.split(".")[-1]}"""
        # remove extension from filename
        filename = ".".join(filename.split(".")[:-1])
    else:
        # set extension to empty if not included
        extension = ""
    try:
        # try to set the number
        # it will throw a ValueError if it doesn't have _1
        number = int(filename.split("_")[-1]) +1
        newfilename = "_".join(filename.split("_")[:-1])
    except ValueError:
        # catch the ValueError and set the number to 1
        number = 1
        newfilename = "_".join(filename.split("_"))
    return f"{newfilename}_{number}{extension}"


def inc_filelist(filelist: list) -> list:
    result = []
    for filename in filelist:
        filename = inc_filename(filename)
        while filename in filelist or filename in result:
            filename = inc_filename(filename)
        result.append(filename)
    return result


print(inc_filename("hotdog_1"))
print(inc_filename("hotdog"))
print(inc_filename("hotdog_1.jpg"))
print(inc_filename("hotdog.jpg"))
print(inc_filename("ho_t_dog_15.jpg"))
print(inc_filename("hotdog_1_91.jpg"))

filelist = [
    "hotdog_1.jpg",
    "hotdog_2.jpg",
    "hotdog_3.jpg",
    "hotdog_4.jpg"
]

print(inc_filelist(filelist))
```

**output**

```
hotdog_2
hotdog_1
hotdog_2.jpg
hotdog_1.jpg
ho_t_dog_16.jpg
hotdog_1_92.jpg
['hotdog_5.jpg', 'hotdog_6.jpg', 'hotdog_7.jpg', 'hotdog_8.jpg']
```